# How do I call a function outside a in a new function and add the value of a parameter to a new variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I´m new to Python and coding and trying to learn, but I can't figure out or find any answers how to call a function outside and use it in another function. I want to run the function to get the result of the function I call. I want to add the result to a variable that already is an INT.

It´s a flip coin game. If the user's answer is correct, add 10 to Money and if the answer is invalid, minus 10.

I´ve tried:

```
Money += flip_coin("hEADS!".title().strip("!?,. "),10)

this produces the following error message:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Here is my code.

```
def flip_coin(guess, bet):
  new_random = random.choice(ls)
  print("You guessed: {0}".format(guess))
  total = 0
  if bet > 0 and bet <= money:
    if (guess == new_random):
      total += bet
      return "Coin flip shows: {0}".format(new_random), "You won {0}".format(total)
```

I want the result `Money+=bet`  in Another function.

Money is a scope variable.

I´m trying to call the function like this, which is wrong:

```
def amt_money(new_money):
  money += flip_coin(guess, bet )
  return money

amt_money(bet)run
```

This is correct (I´m getting this and want to add 10 to money):

```
You guessed: Heads
('Coin flip shows: Heads', 'You won 10')
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 32, in <module>
    amt_money(bet)
NameError: name 'bet' is not defined
```

if:
this is the scopes

```
Money = 100
ls = ["Heads", "Tails"]
```

I want the output: 110 if they won or 90 if they lose.

```
result = flip_coin("heads".title().strip("!?,. "), 5)

tot = []
for res in result[1]:
  if res in result[1]:
    tot += result[1].split(' ')
money += int(tot[2])
```

I did something like this and it worked, I bruted down the string and indexed the "bet" and converted it to int and added it to `money`. This made it to avoid the tulp. I know is not the most Beautiful solution but it did the work. =)

But how do I put this code into a function so I can call it every time I whant to use it?

the question is maybe hard to get, but let me know, I will do my best to reform my question so it´s understandable.

Comment: If the guess is not random coin flip, what do you want it to do? Add zero to the money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if I'm properly answering your question, but I believe you can just make the return value of flip_coin an int and your code would become a lot easier.

```
def flip_coin(guess, bet):
  new_random = random.choice(ls)
  print("You guessed: {0}".format(guess))
  total = 0
  if bet > 0 and bet <= money:
    if (guess == new_random):
      total += bet
      print("Coin flip shows: {0}".format(new_random), "You won {0}".format(total))
      return total # Total if it is correct
    return 0 # 0 if it's the wrong guess
  return -10 # -10 if it is invalid
```

For the final return values, I'm not completely sure if that's what you're looking for.

From there, you can write the amt_money function like so:

```
def amt_money(guess, bet):
  global Money # Calls the global variable
  Money += flip_coin(guess, bet) # Add result to money
  return Money
```

I created a [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sp7m_THXrBo64zUMZCe2cSoCz4AEmA8n) with what I think you want.

Please let me know if this is what you're looking for or if I should edit anything.